# How to use the react-grid-gallery package in GatsbyJS?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I would like to use this [package](https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery) in one of my projects, but I don't really understand how to use it.

This is my gallery page:

```
import React from "react";
import Gallery from "react-grid-gallery";
import {photos} from "../data/data";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";


export default function GalleryPage() {
    return(
        <Layout>
            <SEO title = "Activities"/>
            <div className = "font-monserrat text-red-dark text-4xl font-light"> Photos</div>
            <br/>
            <Gallery photos={photos} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

And it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
```

Comment: Should it be `<Gallery images={photos} />` ?

Comment: @ksav yeah, that was the problem. Thank you! I should've paid more attention:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery#quick-and-dirty-start), the `props` passed to `<Gallery>` component should be `images` instead of `photos`.

```
import React from "react";
import Gallery from "react-grid-gallery";
import {photos} from "../data/data";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";


export default function GalleryPage() {
    return(
        <Layout>
            <SEO title = "Activities"/>
            <div className = "font-monserrat text-red-dark text-4xl font-light"> Photos</div>
            <br/>
            <Gallery images={photos} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```